# Ubuntu 18.04 Graphics Card unclaimed, Broken after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hp, intel, login-screen

I updated Ubuntu 18.04 through the software update screen and it is broken after update. Both graphics card (Intel integrated and nvidia) now shows unclaimed. I was able to fix nvidia card by downloading the proprietary driver from the same above screen but that didn't solve the problem. I am running this along with windows 10. I am only able to login to the system in recovery mode.

```
Linux hp-101 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
`
`$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           2021722    558 2021164    1% /dev
tmpfs          2027757    968 2026789    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6 6152192 192103 5960089    4% /
tmpfs          2027757    242 2027515    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          2027757      5 2027752    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          2027757     18 2027739    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p8 4702208  20314 4681894    1% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1       0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop1       12847  12847       0  100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop0         354    354       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop2       39455  39455       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop3       42235  42235       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop4       27707  27707       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop6        1550   1550       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop5       12823  12823       0  100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop7       27755  27755       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop8       10041  10041       0  100% /snap/core18/1066
/dev/loop9         271    271       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop10        274    274       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop11        733    733       0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop13        354    354       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop12       1577   1577       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop14        734    734       0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop15      10095  10095       0  100% /snap/core18/1668
tmpfs          2027757     32 2027725    1% /run/user/1000
`

` dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04              5.3.0.40.97                                      amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04-edge         5.3.0.40.97                                      amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
`


`sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce MX130]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)`


`lsmod | grep i915
i915                 1818624  0
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
drm                   479232  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
video                  49152  1 i915
```

BIOS secure mode is disabled. I have reinstalled nvidia driver multiple times. I am trying for the last 2 days and have tried most of the suggestions from the internet but no luck so far. will appreciate your time and help if you can guide or suggest something that can solve this problem.

Comment: If you upgraded your system, why are you using an unsupported kernel?  Details are incomplete (or you're running something like Mint & not Ubuntu; that is **not** the kernel of 18.04.4, and installed systems upgraded some time before 18.04.4 ISO was released)

Comment: I downloaded this from here - https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop. I can share more details if required, please let me know what is missing

Comment: Also can you please help me understand how I am using the unsupported kernel if I downloaded it few days back.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 uses the 5.3 kernel and stack found in Ubuntu 19.10 with HWE enabled.  Ubuntu 18.04.4 from original installs or upgrades from prior releases without HWE enabled will use the 4.15 kernel. Your `dpkg -l` shows 5.3 (5.3.0.40) is installed, but you're running 5.0? (5.0.0-23)  Try your updated kernel first! or are you selecting the older kernel to login??  (5.0 was from the 19.04 software stack now EOL and used in 18.04.3, 5.3 is from 19.10's stack (18.04.4) as you have HWE enabled)

Comment: Yes, I am choosing 5.0.0 in recovery mode as 5.3.0 recovery mode hangs on Ubuntu screen

Comment: Please find the answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297325/new-radeon-graphics-with-ubuntu/1320189