# New Radeon Graphics with Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, kernel, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have got a new Thinkpad with a AMD Ryzen 7 processor and Radeon graphics. I have successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it alongside Windows however Ubuntu does not recognise the display, it shows 'Unknown display' in the settings and I can not change the screen resolution. First I tried editing /etc/default/grub in various ways recommended on forums, such as adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1" but that did not work.

Then I tried installing the driver released by AMD (below) but that failed towards the end of the install with a couple of error messages.
https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/re...ed-linux-20-20

I then found people saying that this driver released by AMD is unnecessary and that the Ubuntu kernel 5.7 upwards has inbuilt functionality to handle this. As 20.04 uses kernel 5.4 so I upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.10 so it is using kernel 5.8 but it still doesn't recognise the display. I feel like this is perhaps the solution but am I missing something obvious?

Is there a different Linux distribution that will recognise the display?

I have also tried installing 18.04 but that did not work either.

All I want to do is change the screen resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To further demonstrate the issue, if I run this command to list the graphic driver: `sudo lshw -c video`

I get this response:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: d1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f memory:460000000-46fffffff memory:470000000-4701fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:fd300000-fd37ffff
```

Comment: Hi Nmath, the screen is working in the sense I can view it but I just can not adjust it in the settings. The resolution is stuck at 1920 x 1080, I would prefer a resolution such as 1366 x 768 so that icons, text, everything appears larger on the screen. I hope this makes sense, does it?

Comment: The native resolution is 1920 x 1080. I thought lowering the resolution would be ok as it is the same ratio 16:9. Anyway I tried enabling fractional scaling and setting it to 125% or 150% but it just displays at 200%. It only seems to be able to display at 100% or 200% and presumably this is because of my original problem, there's no driver for the screen. I've seen posts of others saying they have it 'working' but I'm unsure if that means they are able to adjust the settings. Both 100% and 200% are unusable for me personally. Thanks for your advice, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You might want to try a different flavor of Ubuntu.  GNOME is not easily customizable.  For comparison, Kubuntu (KDE) has system settings that allow you to set the font and font size of different aspects of the UI.  There's nothing in your question or comments that leads me to believe that you are missing any drivers.  It's extremely uncommon for a display to need a driver. If the native resolution is 1920x1080 and you're able to use this resolution, there is nothing wrong.  I think you are just not satisfied with icon/text size. That does not mean there is actually a problem.

Comment: Thanks Nmath, I now have Kubuntu installed and am happy with how I can scale the screen display. I believe the issue with Ubuntu is that the graphics in my laptop are too new for the AMDGPU module in kernal 5.04. I have seen an article saying that tests with kernel 5.10 have been successful so hopefully they will eventually release a LTS version that can handle these newer AMD graphics.